# app crashed when using Geolocation.getCurrentPosition in react native máp

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

Can anyone tell me how to fix this app crash bug.
I use react-native-maps with react-native-geolocation-service .
When I press the update my location button, the app crashes without knowing why. I have configured and granted the location permission as above but do not know where the error is? Hope everyone can help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmxKu.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGTb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOA9q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mugsb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lero6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9xp.png)

Comment: Hey @Văn, the problem statement requires some more details like for example: what is the error message when the app crashed? Probably you can give this a try: `Geolocation?.getCurrentPosition`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Logcat in Android Studio? I think you will find the root cause by checking the Error logs.